# Extracting values from route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to retrieve `contact_id` and `hash` values from my route. In my `PictureController` I have pictures function where I want to use them.

**My route**:

```
Route::get('/static/contacts/{contact_id}/picture/{hash}', [
  'as' => 'platform.api.contacts.picture.hash',
  'uses' => 'PictureController@pictures'
]);
```

I suppose this is not enough?

```
public function picture ($contactId, $hash)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `{contact_id}` translates to `$contactId` in your controller, or if it should be `$contact_id`. Also, you specify `PictureController@pictures`, but your function name is `picture` (no "s"). If you address those potential issues, then your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Route contains little wrong.

```
Route::get('/static/contacts/{contact_id}/picture/{hash}', [ 'as' => 'platform.api.contacts.picture.hash', 'uses' => 'PictureController@pictures' ]);
```

Insted of use

```
Route::get('/static/contacts/{contact_id}/picture/{hash}', [ 'as' => 'platform.api.contacts.picture.hash', 'uses' => 'PictureController@picture' ]);
```

Your function name was wrong as you used in controller. Look at the function name in route pictures and controller you used picture.

Comment: This should work then right ? public function picture ($contactId, $hash)

Comment: Better you should use Route::get('/static/contacts/{contact_id}/picture/{hash}', 'PictureController@picture')->name('platform.api.contacts.picture.hash');